# Incorrect dimensions for matrix multiplication when multiplying pi*a

Tags: arrays, matlab, multiplication

I've created this code and it gives me this error message:

> Error using *
> Incorrect dimensions for matrix multiplication.
> Error in poli3 = sin(pi*a) ...

Below I show one function used in the code. I don't know if the problem comes from the value given by `derivadan` or what.

```matlab
x = -1:0.01:1; % Intervalo en el que se evaluará el polinomio de Taylor

y = sin(pi*x); % Función

a = 0; 

derivada3 = derivadan(0.01, 3, a);
derivada7 = derivadan(0.01, 7, a);

derivada3_vec = repmat(derivada3, size(x - a));
derivada7_vec = repmat(derivada7, size(x - a));


poli3 = sin(pi*a) + derivada3_vec*(x - a) + (derivada3_vec*(x - a).^2)/factorial(2) + (derivada3_vec*(x - a).^3)/factorial(3);
poli7 = sin(pi*a) + derivada7_vec*(x - a) + (derivada7_vec*(x - a).^2)/factorial(2) + (derivada7_vec*(x - a).^3)/factorial(3) + (derivada7_vec*(x - a).^4)/factorial(4) + (derivada7_vec*(x - a).^5)/factorial(5) + (derivada7_vec*(x - a).^6)/factorial(6) + (derivada7_vec*(x - a).^7)/factorial(7);


figure
plot(x, poli3, 'r', x, poli7, 'b')
legend('Taylor grau 3', 'Taylor grau 7')
title('Grafica Taylor 3 grau vs Grafica Taylor 7 grau')



function Yd = derivadan(h, grado, vecX)
  Yd = zeros(size(vecX)); 
  
  for i = 1:grado
    
    Yd = (vecX(2:end) - vecX(1:end-1)) / h; 
    
    vecX = Yd;
  end
end
```

Comment: Also please read [mre]. Have you redefined the function `pi`? Type `which pi` at your MATLAB command prompt.

Comment: yes it is redefined, problem has to do with size of multiplication

Comment: If you've redefined `pi`, then `pi` no longer is `3.14159...`. It likely returns an array now, which has a size not compatible with `a`, so `pi*a` is wrong. You should not redefine the standard functions. Delete your `pi` function, or rename it, and this code will work again.

Comment: so ishould delete y = sin(pi*x);?

Comment: Let's backtrack. Did you type `which pi` at the MATLAB Command Prompt? It should tell you which function is `pi`. If it's a function you wrote yourself (either intentionally or unintentionally) it'll give you the full path to it. That is the file you need to delete or rename. It is also possible that you defined a variable `pi`. `clear pi` should get rid of it.

Comment: i've already erase it and still gives me same error

Comment: i guess has to do with dimensions maybe?

Comment: How do you know the problem is related to "pi"? The error message seems to reference a line with a lot of other stuff on it.

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB one can go 2 ways when developing **taylor series**; the **hard way** and the **easy way**.

As asked, first **the HARD way** :

```
close all;clear all;clc
dx=.01
x = -1+dx:dx:1-dx; 

y = sin(pi*x); 

a =0; 
[va,na]=find(x==a)

n1=3

D3y=zeros(n1,numel(x));
for k=1:1:n1
    D3y(k,1:end-k)=dn(dx,k,y);   
end

T3=y(na)+sum(1./factorial([1:n1])'.*D3y(:,na).*((x(1:end-n1)-a)'.^[1:n1])',1);

n2=7

D7y=zeros(n2,numel(x));
for k=1:1:n2
    D7y(k,1:end-k)=dn(dx,k,y);
end

T7=y(na)+sum([1./factorial([1:n2])]'.*D7y(:,na).*((x(1:end-n2)-a)'.^[1:n2])',1);


figure(1);ax=gca
plot(ax,x(1:numel(T7)),T3(1:numel(T7)),'r')
grid on;hold on
xlabel('x')

plot(ax,x(1:numel(T7)),T7(1:numel(T7)),'b--')
plot(ax,x(1:numel(T7)),y(1:numel(T7)),'g')

axis(ax,[-1 1 -1.2 1.2])
legend('T3', 'T7','sin(pi*x)','Location','northeastoutside')
```

[image]

the support function being

```
function Yd = dn(h, n, vecX)
  Yd = zeros(size(vecX)); 
  
  for i = 1:n
    
    Yd = (vecX(2:end) - vecX(1:end-1))/h; 
    
    vecX = Yd;
  end

end
```

Explanation

**1.-** The custom function `derivadan` that I call `dn` shortens one sample for every unit up in `grado` where `grado` is the derivative order.

For instance, the 3rd order derivative is going to be 3 samples shorter than the input function.

This causes product mismatch and when later on attempting plot it's going to cause plot error.

**2.-** To avoid such mismatchs **ALL** vectors shortened **to the size of the shortest one**.

```
x(1:end-a)
```

is `a` samples shorter than `x` and `y` and can be used as reference vector in plot.

**3.-** Call function `derivadan` (that I call `dn`) correctly

`dn` expects as 3rd input (3rd from left) a vector, the function values to differentiate, yet you are calling derivadan with a in 3rd input field. `a` is scalar and you have set it null. Fixed it.

```
derivada3 = derivadan(0.01, 3, a);
```

should be called

```
derivada3 = derivadan(0.01, 3, y);
```

same for `derivada7`

**4.-** So

```
error using * ...
error in poly3=sin(pi*a) ...
```

MATLAB doesn't particularly mean that there's an error right on `sin(pi*a)` , that could be, but it's not the case here >

**MATLAB is saying : THERE'S AN ERROR IN LINE STARTING WITH**

```
poly3=sin(pi*a) ..
```

MATLAB aborts there.

Same error is found in next line starting with

```
poly7 ..
```

Since `sin(pi*a)=0` because `a=0` yet all other terms in sum for `poly3` are `repmat` outcomes with different sizes all sizes being different and >1 hence **attempting product of different sizes**.

Operator `*` requires all terms have `same size`.

**5.-** Syntax Error

```
derivada3_vec = repmat(derivada3, size(x - a))
```

is built is not correct

this line repeats `size(x)` times the nth order derivative !

it's a really long sequence.

Now **the EASY way**

**6.-** MATLAB already has command `taylor`

```
syms x;T3=taylor(sin(pi*x),x,0)
T3 = (pi^5*x^5)/120 - (pi^3*x^3)/6 + pi*x


syms x;T3=taylor(sin(pi*x),x,0,'Order',3)
T3 = pi*x

syms x;T3=taylor(sin(pi*x),x,0,'Order',7)
T7 = (pi^5*x^5)/120 - (pi^3*x^3)/6 + pi*x

T9=taylor(sin(pi*x),x,0,'Order',9)
T9 =- (pi^7*x^7)/5040 + (pi^5*x^5)/120 - (pi^3*x^3)/6 + pi*x
```

It really simplfies taylor series development because it readily generates all that is needed to such endeavour :

```
syms f(x)
f(x) = sin(pi*x);
a=0
T_default = taylor(f, x,'ExpansionPoint',a);

T8 = taylor(f, x, 'Order', 8,'ExpansionPoint',a);
T10 = taylor(f, x, 'Order', 10,'ExpansionPoint',a);

figure(2)
fplot([T_default T8 T10 f])
axis([-2 3 -1.2 1.2])
hold on
plot(a,f(a),'r*')
grid on;xlabel('x')
title(['Taylor Series Expansion x =' num2str(a)])
```

[image]

```
a=.5
T_default = taylor(f, x,'ExpansionPoint',a);

T8 = taylor(f, x, 'Order', 8,'ExpansionPoint',a);
T10 = taylor(f, x, 'Order', 10,'ExpansionPoint',a);

figure(3)
fplot([T_default T8 T10 f])
axis([-2 3 -1.2 1.2])
hold on
plot(a,f(a),'r*')
grid on;xlabel('x')
title(['Taylor Series Expansion x =' num2str(a)])
```

[image]

```
a=1
T_default = taylor(f, x,'ExpansionPoint',a);

T8 = taylor(f, x, 'Order', 8,'ExpansionPoint',a);
T10 = taylor(f, x, 'Order', 10,'ExpansionPoint',a);

figure(4)
fplot([T_default T8 T10 f])
axis([-2 3 -1.2 1.2])
hold on
plot(a,f(a),'r*')
grid on;xlabel('x')
title(['Taylor Series Expansion x =' num2str(a)])
```

[image]

thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

I checked the line that you were having issues with; it seems that the error is in the `derivada3_vec*(x - a)` (as well as in the other terms that use `derivada3_vec`).

Looking at the variable itself: `derivada3_vec` is an empty vector. Going back further, the `derivada3` variable is also an empty vector.

**Your issue is in your function `derivadan`.** You're inputting a 1x1 vector (`a = [0]`), but the function assumes that `a` is at least 1x2 (or 2x1).

I suspect there are other issues, but this is the cause of your error message.